# postgis - wrong ST_Distance with geography points

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I'm trying to calculate the distance between to geographical points, but the calculated distance is bigger than the real one (from Google Maps).

The `location` column in postgresql is define as `geography(Geometry,4326)`, and the query is:

> select ST_Distance(u1.location, u2.location)

For example, I have a pair of points for which the distance is:

- 160 km on Google Maps
- 190 km calculated with the above query.

What can be wrong? I may be missing a projection matter.

I have also tried the following query, but I get the same results:

> select ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText(ST_AsText(u1.location)),
>   ST_GeogFromText(ST_AsText(u2.location)))

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10148241/3463640:
I had inverted lon & lat when creating points.

Comment: Yes I tried to do so yesterday, but it appears I have to wait for 2 days.